# composing setState in react with Ramda

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming

I'm building a react app using Ramda. When the page loads I want to load some data and put it in my state so it looks like this:

```
{
    "datasets": [foo, bar]
}
```

So I've used the componentDidMount method to achieve this.

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/api/dataset/')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(datasets => this.setState(R.assoc('datasets', datasets)))
}
```

This works, but then I thought I could make it even slicker using R.compose

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/api/dataset/')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(R.compose(this.setState, R.assoc('datasets')))
}
```

This doesn't work, it gives me the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'enqueueSetState' of undefined
  at r.setState (ReactBaseClasses.js:62)
  at _pipe.js:3
  at _arity.js:14
  at <anonymous>
```

Why does this happen? Does it have something to do with the binding of 'this'?

Comment: this.setState.bind(this) ?

Comment: Thank you, adding this.setState = this.setState.bind(this) in constructor solved the issue

Comment: Lovely! Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in your `constructor` method

```
constructor () {
  super();
  this.setState.bind(this);
}
```